# Why do two computations of a black hole's volume differ?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon, volume

According to [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/0801.1734) the volume of a black hole is zero. The volume of a black hole is calculated as the integral of (squareroots of) determinants over space (time is held constant):

$$V=\int _{r_{inner}}^{r^{outer}} \sqrt{g} d^3x,$$

where

$$g=\frac{r^2sin^2\theta}{1-\frac{2m}{r}}.$$

The determinant $g$ is calculated from the Schwarzschild metric (for which $dt=0$ if time is constant). The integration is done between two surfaces. One with radius $r^{outer}=2m$, the Schwarzschild radius, and one with $r=r_{inner}$. Then it is written that on no Schwarzschild-$t=constant$-slice the $r$-coordinate extends to less than $r=2m$. Which means that the limits of the integral are the same and thus, the integral is zero. Which means that the volume is zero.
So the integration is done between two surfaces which have equal radii. You could say that there is no spatial inside, nor a temporal one. All matter resides always in zero volume (though finite area), as seen by a distant observer. This is why the picture that represent the holes (if space were 2-d) as a 2-d surface with an infinite deep throat (excuse the expression) is somewhat misleading. In this picture, the 2-d space has an area (volume) which even seems to extent to infinity. The area of on infinite cylinder with decreasing radius, which is greater than the area of a flat disc with a Schwarzschild radius.
So while an external observer sees all matter end up on a 2-d shell, an observer inside the hole sees the infalling matter being distributed over a volume. I'm not sure if this is related to the ADS/CFT correpondence (maximum information contant of a volume is the maximum information content of the area in which the volume is enclosed).
However that might be, in the same article it is stated that the volume of a black hole, if the spacetime is expressed in [Kerr-Schild](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric) coordinates, is:

$$V=6,567(2m)^3$$

Why is this volume not zero too?

Are Kerr-Schild coordinates referring to the coordinates as seen by an observer inside the hole? I don't understand why it is written that "Convincing oneself of the zero result of Section 3 is made easier by considering a different time-independent form" (the Kerr-Schild form).

Comment: Have you tried reading the article?

Comment: @mmeent i did. That's why I ask the question. Are Kerr-Schild coordinates referring to the coordinates as seen by an observer inside the hole? I don't understand why it is written that "Convincing oneself of the zero result of Section 3 is made easier by considering a different time-independent form" (the Kerr-Schild form).